# How would I make a loop in java that will ask the user to pick a class from the array list and if they enter an invalid value to ask again?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PartyTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Party party = new Party();
    String[] classNames = {"theif","warrior","wizard","steve","bard"};
    
    Hero Carmilla = new Hero("Carmilla");
    Hero Alucard = new Hero("Alucard");
    Hero Steve = new Hero("steve");
    Hero Sypha = new Hero("sypha");
    
    System.out.println("The avaliable classes are:\n" );
    for(int i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(classNames[i]);
    }
    
    Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the class for Carmilla\n");
    String nameC = ask.next();
    Boolean temp;
```

I was attempting to do a while loop but I was not sure what conditions to use

```
    while(temp = true) {
        if(nameC.equalsIgnoreCase("theif")) {
            Carmilla.sethClass(nameC);
            temp = false;;
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid class try again");
            
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Carmilla);
```

Hero class just sets the values for everything, I would use (depending on the name of the person I'm calling) `Carmilla.sethClass(nameC)', which just sets the name of the chosen class to the hero class.
I want to ask the user what class they would like to set for each person(they are the names stated with Hero in front of them)and if the user does not type one of the classNames value then they are told that its an invalid statement and to try again, which will then ask again what class they want for (in this example) Carmilla.

Comment: so you want to take classNames from user and if he enters incorrect, ask him to reenter, what if he enters the right thing? 
why are using carmilla.sethClass(nameC) ?

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani I just edited the question - but basically I ask them what class they would like to assign Carmilla (or any of the other 4 names) and if they type one of the choices stated in the array then that choice will call Carmilla.sethClass(nameC), which just assigns that person their class name.

Comment: do you need that, Enter the class for Carmilla, 
is it fine we print this line " Class for Carmilla has been set ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish it.

The class with main method is below. A few notes about it. First, I made the Party class just an ArrayList of Hero objects, since I'm assuming that a party is just a collection of heroes. This makes asking names for each of the four heroes easier because we can loop through the party list.

Next, I moved the instantiation of the Hero objects into the initialization of the party so that the list already contains our Hero objects.

I utilized a for-each loop to check and assign classes to each Hero and a while loop to redirect the user back if they entered an invalid class. I check whether the class is valid using the boolean `validClass`. The final output of running this is shown at the very bottom.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PartyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Hero> party = Arrays.asList(new Hero("Carmilla"),
                                     new Hero("Alucard"),
                                     new Hero("steve"),
                                     new Hero("sypha"));
    String[] classNames = { "theif", "warrior", "wizard", "steve", "bard" };

    Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (Hero hero : party) {
        if (hero.getHclass()
                .equals("Default")) {
        boolean validClass = false;
        while (!validClass) {
            System.out.println("Enter the class for " + hero.getName());
            String hClass = ask.nextLine();

            for (String name : classNames) {
            if (hClass.equals(name)) {
                validClass = true;
            }

            }
            if (validClass) {
            hero.setHclass(hClass);
            }
        }
        }
    }

    party.forEach(hero -> {
        System.out.println(hero.getName() + " has class " + hero.getHclass());
    });
    }

}
```

The Hero class:

```
public class Hero {
    private String name;
    private String hclass = "Default";
    
    public Hero(String name) {
    this.name = name;

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getHclass() {
        return hclass;
    }
    public void setHclass(String hclass) {
        this.hclass = hclass;
    }
    
    

}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Party is actually used to put randomly 3 characters into a party together (obviously I didn't mention this so you wouldn't have known), but this helps a lot - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use **for-each** loop to match the entered name against the classNames

### Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
//Hero class replace with your class
class Hero{
    String name="";
    String className="";
    public Hero(){}
    public Hero(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    public void sethClass(String className){
        this.className=className;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Name : "+name+" className : "+className;
    }
}
public class PartyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        //Party party = new Party();
        String[] classNames = {"theif","warrior","wizard","steve","bard"};

        Hero Carmilla = new Hero("Carmilla");
        Hero Alucard = new Hero("Alucard");
        Hero Steve = new Hero("steve");
        Hero Sypha = new Hero("sypha");

        System.out.println("The avaliable classes are:\n" );
        for(int i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(classNames[i]);
        }

        //Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the class for Carmilla\n");
        boolean matched=false;
        while(!matched) {
            String nameC = br.readLine();
            //Use for-each loop to match the entered name 
            for(String name : classNames){
                if(nameC.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    Carmilla.sethClass(nameC);
                    matched=true;//Matched
                    break;

                }
            }
            if(matched)break;
            System.out.println("Invalid class try again\n");
        }
        System.out.println(Carmilla);
    }
}
```

### OUTPUT:

```
$ javac PartyTest.java && java PartyTest 
The avaliable classes are:

theif
warrior
wizard
steve
bard
Enter the class for Carmilla

blaba
Invalid class try again

qwertr
Invalid class try again

Wizard
Name : Carmilla className : Wizard
```